# Android TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to add image buttons in a table layout at run time.
My table contains 100 rows and 20 columns so i also want to add scroll in that screen.
I want to scroll that images at Horizontally and vertically also because my rows and columns are high.After every 20 rows i want to add button with full width of the screen.
So how can i do that.Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirement of displaying images(thumbnails) there is something called GRIDVIEW in android. Where you can display images in rows and columns and also put contents to them dynamically(personally not tried).

Check this sample:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html